# How can I count how many duplicates there are for each distinct value in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, count, sum, distinct

I have a table:

```
ref,type
1,red
2,red
3,green
4,blue
5,black
6,black
```

I want the result of a sqlite query to be:

```
red,2
green,1
blue,1
black,2
```

I think the hardest thing to do is find a question to match my problem?  Then I am sure the answer is around the corner....

:)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A quick google gave me this: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg38339.html

```
select type, count(type) from table group by type;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, what did you search for in Google?

Comment: `sqlite count dupicates`. Easy as that.

Answer (score 129):

My quick google with the terms "count unique values sqlite3" landed me on this post. However, I was trying to count the overall number of unique values, instead of how many duplicates there are for each category.

From Chris's result table above, I just want to know how many unique colors there are. The correct answer here would be four [4].

This can be done using
`select count(DISTINCT type) from table;`

Comment: And can you provide an example of the best way to use this query. Would it be `long count = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select count(DISTINCT type) from table", null);`

Comment: @Bhoom, count(DISTINCT type) is what I looking for today.

Comment: not what the asker was asking so no up-vote but exactly with I needed, thank you! Also I aliased the column name as `total` like this, `select count(distinct type) as total from table"

Comment: this is not what the question asked

Comment: This is not what the question asked. This is off-topic

Comment: Not sure where I should move this solution. But, I guess most people who landed here and upvote the answer were not really looking for the original poster's question, but merely trying to find the unique count using sqlite3. 
Should I delete the answer, then?