# how to write proper count sqlite command?

Tags: sqlite

I count the different x in the table with :

```
create table tmp as 
select  distinct  x  from balance ;
select count(x) from tmp ;
```

How can i combine them into one simple sqlite command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a count distinct in sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522607/how-can-i-do-a-count-distinct-in-sqlite)

Comment: no ,`select distinct x,count(x)  from cash ;` can not work for me,it is a wrong result,and `select  x,count(x)  from cash ;` too .

Comment: `select count(DISTINCT x) from cash;` can work for me,thinks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column)